# R.O.S installation on Beaglebone without internet access

Tags: ros, usb, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a BeagleBone that already has Ubuntu running on it.  I want to install R.O.S on it but it can't connect to the internet for some reason.  I wanted to know if there was a way to put all of the R.O.S files into a flash drive that I could use to install it on the Beaglebone or if there was a way to copy the R.O.S that's running on my P.C and transfer it to the Beaglebone and if so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37098/r.o.s-installation-on-beaglebone-without-internet-access./) by [bcesarto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2690/bcesarto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My favourite tool for this is `apt-offline`, as explained in this post: [ROS offline installation](http://answers.ros.org/question/33469/ros-offline-installation/).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1